# Cisco 3925/k9 sub-interface vlan support

Tags: cisco, vlan, licensing, ios

I've got a brand new cisco router 3925/k9. I wanted to set up a router on a stick on my network, but it turns out it doesn't support vlan sub-interfaces. I did it multiple times in gns3 simulator on other routers, so I am familiar with IOS commands and concepts. I believe this must be a licensing issue, but so far I couldn't find anything on cisco website that explains it.
Here is some info from "show version":

```
ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M13, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
System image file is "flash0:c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M2.bin"
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
1 terminal line
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
DRAM configuration is 72 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
250880K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)

License Info:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Technology    Technology-package           Technology-package
              Current       Type           Next reboot
------------------------------------------------------------------
ipbase        ipbasek9      Permanent      ipbasek9
security      securityk9    Permanent      securityk9
uc            None          None           None
data          None          None           None
```

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a clue what I can do to enable vlan support on this router.

Comment: Why haven't you just asked Cisco Tech Support?

Comment: According to the feature navigator your router should support 802.1q VLANs. What config are you trying to enter? Is it `encapsulation dot1q <xx>` under the subinterface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cisco router 3925/k9 fully supports 802.1q VLANs. The problem was lack of my attention. I totally forgot that **encapuslation dot1q**  is available in **subinterface** and not the main interface.
so the correct config for enabling vlans on cisco router should look like this:

```
Router_A(config)#interface fastethernet 0/0
Router_A(config-if)#no shutdown
Router_A(config-if)#interface fastethernet 0/0.1
Router_A(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 1
Router_A(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
Router_A(config-if)#interface fastethernet 0/0.2
Router_A(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 10
Router_A(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
Router_A(config-if)#interface fastethernet 0/0.3
Router_A(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 20
Router_A(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.7.1 255.255.255.0
Router_A(config-subif)#end
```